# search folder names and picture names on search server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-express

Is there a way to search folder names and pictures names on search server express 2010?

I am trying to search libraries on SharePoint Foundation that contains pictures and other files inside folders. Those folders are names of categories that could be helpful if they are returned in the search. Currently only contents inside documents are returned.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the search server express does search pictures names and folders names as I wanted. I tested it and it in fact does it and so no need for any other configuration.